# Extracting Spot Color equivalents from TIFF

Tags: c, colors, tiff

I'm trying to get the Spot color information from a TIFF file, it normally shows up under 'channels' in Photoshop.  Each extra channel would have a name, which is usually a Pantone swatch name, and a CMYK equivalent.

So far, I'm getting the TIFFTAG_PHOTOSHOP with libtiff, and stepping through the blocks within.  I'm finding the IRB WORD 0x03EE, which gives me the channel names, and IRB WORD 0x03EF which gives me their color equivalents...

BUT the color equivalents are in [CIELab](http://dba.med.sc.edu/price/irf/Adobe_tg/models/cielab.html) format (Luminance, and two axis of color space data)  so I'm trying to use [littleCMS](http://www.littlecms.com/) to convert just a few TIFF packed Lab color to CMYK.

My question:  Is there an easier way?  The CMYK is just an approximation of the Pantone, so if there was a quick rough translation from Lab to CMYK, I would use it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was to use the photoshop docs to parse out the binary photoshop block in the tiff file and grab the fields I needed with bit manipulation.

littleCMS did the job of LAB -> CMYK just right.

Comment: It's good to hear that you found a solution your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by *showing* the code you wrote, rather than merely describing it.